# Remove trailing slash from URL/folder but do not redirect subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using `mod_rewrite`. The `.htaccess` contains this line:

```
# redirect old references
Redirect 301 /folder/ http://www.donain.de/folder
```

This works fine execpt for one thing: All requests to subfolders are redirected as well. For example: `/folder/hello` is redirected to `/folder`. How can I prevent this?

I know that I can determine the start of an expression using `^` in a `.htaccess` file. But I can't figure out to say "*stop this rule there*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RedirectMatch` for regex support:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/?$ http://www.donain.de/folder
```